# DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

Tags: asp.net, dom, telerik, internet-explorer-9, domexception

In one aspx page which is running in IE9 got following script Error message. That page also having telerik controls.

Does anybody have experince with this ?

```
Message: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)
Line: 3422
Char: 8
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/AbcWeb/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen%3a1f68db6e-ab92-4c56-8744-13e09bf43565%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen%3a183fb741-216d-4765-9b46-4a1f5d38fdd7%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen%3a1f68db6e-ab92-4c56-8744-13e09bf43565%3a76254418%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2010.2.929.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen%3a183fb741-216d-4765-9b46-4a1f5d38fdd7%3a874f8ea2%3a24ee1bba%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a9cdfc6e7
```

Comment: the URI is localhost (so nobody except you is able to have a look at it)

Comment: Well what's on line 3422 in that file?

Comment: this is not too localized, I have seen this on many sites and the accepted answer below is the solution I typically use.

Comment: I vote to re-open. This question and answer just helped me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IE9 was released in March 2011. In the URL you posted, I see the Telerik version is 2010.2.929.40 (September 2010). Perhaps this is just a compatibility issue with the older Telerik version and the new browser? What you can do is either get a newer RadControls build, or force your page to use IE8 rendering. For more information about IE compatibility modes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

TL;DR - Add the following meta tag in the header of your page and see if it makes a difference:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" >
```

Comment: This did not work for me. In IE9 I had to put IE=8 rather than IE=IE8.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ´<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >´ worked for me. In my case I think the problem was in an older version of mootools. This fix gives me some time to upgrade...

Answer (score 4):

From the [HTML::DOM::Exception - The Exception interface for HTML::DOM](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/HTML-DOM/HTML/DOM/Exception.pm.html)

you can see the reason for this as

```
INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

    If an invalid character is specified, such as in a name.
```

Comment: Also, the official link: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMException-INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR